# she was vs she had been

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Which one is correct?

> 1. She **was** on OCP for 5 years and had stopped it since 2005.
> 2. She **had been** on OCP for 5 years and had stopped it since 2005.

Comment: Both sentence sound incorrect to me. Why not "She was on OCP for 5 years before she stopped in the year 2005.

Answer (score 1):

**Past Perfect Tense**
It is used about something that happened before another action in the past (which is expressed by simple past tense).

- It is often used with already, yet, just, even, by.
- It indicates an earlier past event or situation.

**Past Tense**
It is used to talk about a completed action in a time before now.
 - It is used with frequency: often, sometimes, always.
 - It is used with a definite point in time: last week, when, yesterday, weeks ago.
 - It is used with an indefinite point in time.

It means the correct sentence is:
She had been on OCP for 5 years and stopped it since 2005.

[Simple past tense](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/)
[Learn English](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/past-simple-or-past-perfect)